# how to eager load in a Many to Many relationship in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, loading, eager

My `user table` and `item table` are related by a many to many relationship, the `item table` has some data in foreign tables, example `color table` I have a pivot table that relates the two.
My question is, if I want to retrieve all the items associated to a user with a color how do I get them with eager loading?

I know that `$user->item` will retrieve all the items for that user.

But if I want to eager load all the items for that user with the color attributes in one query, how do I do it?
At the moment I am looping through the items associated to the user and lazy loading every data I need, for example

```
foreach($user->item as $i){

      echo($i->item->color)

}
```

This means every cycle makes a new query...

here the models:

User model:

```
public function item(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\item')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

item model:

```
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
```

and this the schema for the pivot table

```
Schema::create('item_user', function(Blueprint $table) {

            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unsignedInteger('item_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('item_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('items')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: can you show or models or your relationships

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use a [Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Eager loading is done using `with()`: in your instance you could use the following:

```
public function item(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\item')->withTimestamps()->with('color');
}
```

This will eager load the color on the "item". However you can also eager load immediately on the User model in your controller:

```
User::with('items.color')->find(1);
```

> I'm not sure based on your code that the relations/model is like this, but you get the point I guess.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the model as you suggested. Apparently now $user->items will get all the user items + color in 3 queries (?)

Comment: Can you post your `items` relation? I only modified the `item` relation which is a belongsToMany, your `items` relation is probably a `hasMany` ?

Comment: I already posted the relations in the main question. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: You're calling the plural `items` method on the `User` model, but the only method you've posted is the singular `item` which is a belongsToMany. If you'd had a plural items method it would have been a `hasMany` relation probably..

Comment: I have a many to many relationship between user and item. The code is only an example.